# How many Zombie maps are there in Call Of Duty: Black Ops 1?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-black-ops, cod-black-ops-zombies

I love COD: Black Ops, especially **Zombie Mode**. But to start out with, there's only one map you can play, *Kino Der Toten*. So I used cheat codes to unlock The maps *Five* and *Dead Ops Arcade*. And those maps are really fun. But are there any more that you can play? If so, can you unlock them with cheat codes to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zombies mode in Black Ops features the maps

***"Kino Der Toten"***. (Unlocked immediately)

Upon completion of the Campaign, or typing in "3ARC UNLOCK" on the Computer Console in the Main Menu, the map ***"Five"*** would be unlocked.

Also, typing in either "DOA" or "3ARC UNLOCK" on the Computer Console would unlock the map "***Dead Ops Arcade***".

More maps may be purchased via Downloadable Content (DLC) or pre-ordering the Hardened/Prestige Editions.

The Hardened and Prestige Edition include the four revamped versions of ***"Nacht Der Untoten", "Verruct", "Shi No Numa", and "Der Riese"***.

First Strike includes ***"Ascension"***

Escalation includes ***"Call of the Dead"***

Annihilation includes ***"Shangri-La"***

and Rezurrection includes ***"Moon"*** and the ***revamped versions of "Nacht Der Untoten", "Verrückt", "Shi No Numa", and "Der Riese".***

A total of ***12 maps*** (unless Rezurrections revamped maps are different than the other revamps making it ***16 maps***)

[Wiki](https://nazizombies.fandom.com/wiki/Call_of_Duty:_Black_Ops)

Comment: So you have to buy all of the other maps?

Comment: Yes, they are all DLC

Comment: this probably sounds stupid, but what does DLC mean?

Comment: DLC is any downloadable content that a publisher releases for a game. There are a few cases where DLC is free but most of the time, including in Black Ops you need to buy them.

Comment: Do you know how much they are? And do you have to have a PSN account?

Comment: I don't know how much the they are, they could be on sale or just had their price reduced from lack of popularity making internet results untrustworthy. And you shouldn't need a PSN account to buy anything unless it's for online multiplayer.